# Linux differences between consecutive lines

Tags: linux, bash, line, difference

I need to loop trough `n` lines of a file and for any `i between 1 and n - 1` to get the difference `line(n - 1) - line(n)`.

And here is the source file:

```
root@syncro:/var/www# cat cron.log | grep "/dev/vda"
/dev/vda          20418M 14799M     4595M  77% /
/dev/vda          20418M 14822M     4572M  77% /
/dev/vda          20418M 14846M     4548M  77% /
/dev/vda          20418M 14867M     4527M  77% /
/dev/vda          20418M 14888M     4506M  77% /
/dev/vda          20418M 14910M     4484M  77% /
/dev/vda          20418M 14935M     4459M  78% /
/dev/vda          20418M 14953M     4441M  78% /
/dev/vda          20418M 14974M     4420M  78% /
/dev/vda          20418M 15017M     4377M  78% /
/dev/vda          20418M 15038M     4356M  78% /
root@syncro:/var/www# cat cron.log | grep "/dev/vda" | cut -b 36-42 | tr -d " M"
4595
4572
4548
4527
4506
4484
4459
4441
4420
4377
4356
```

those `/dev/vda...` lines are logged hourly with `df -BM` in `cron.log` file and the difference between lines will reveal the hourly disk consumption.

So, the expected output will be:

```
23 (4595 - 4572)
24 (4572 - 4548)
...
43 (4420 - 4377)
21 (4377 - 4356)
```

I don't need the text between `(` and `)`, I put it here for explanation only.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got you correctly, but the following `awk` script should work:

```
awk '{if(NR>1){print _n-$4};_n=$4}' your.file
```

Output:

```
23
24
21
21
22
25
18
21
43
21
```

You **don't need** the other programs in the pipe. Just:

```
awk '/\/dev\/vda/ {if(c++>0){print _n-$4};_n=$4}' src/checkout-plugin/a.txt
```

will be enough. The regex on start of the `awk` scripts tells awk to apply the following block only to lines which match the pattern. A side effect is that `NR` can't be used anymore to detect the "second line" in which the calculation starts. I introduced a custome counter `c` for that purpose.

Also note that `awk` will remove the `M` on it's own, because the column has been used in a numeric calculation.

Comment: Nice answer. You could maybe consider showing OP how to add pattern to select lines starting with `/dev/vda` so he can just run `awk '/^\/dev\/vda/ ....' OriginalLogFile, i.e. without his needing to grep first.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Sure, the other programs in the pipe aren't required. Check my update.

Comment: nice one, +1 for you and @MarkSetchell. One more thing to do: I expected from an input of 10 lines to get an output of 9 lines. I will mark your answer as the accepted one if you can do that. So far, thank you

Comment: yeap that (c++) done his work :) ... Thank you, problem solved!